# Cannot use golang generics variable in function call

Tags: go, generics

I am trying to understand generics implementation in go1.18. In my test example, I am storing a series of test cases and attempting to call a function variable. Unfortunately, I am getting an error in the **EvalCases** function when I try to use the variable *tc.input*, I receive the following error:

> cannot use input (variable of type T constrained by Inputer) as type
> string in argument to fn

Why am I receiving that error, and how do I fix it?

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

type BoolCase func(string) bool

type Inputer interface {
    int | float64 | ~string
}

type Wanter interface {
    Inputer | bool
}

type TestCase[T Inputer, U Wanter] struct {
    input T
    want  U
}

type TestConditions[T Inputer, U Wanter] map[string]TestCase[T, U]

// IsNumeric validates that a string is either a valid int64 or float64
func IsNumeric(s string) bool {
    _, err := strconv.ParseFloat(s, 64)
    return err == nil
}

func EvalCases[T Inputer, U Wanter](cases TestConditions[T, U], fn BoolCase) {

    for name, tc := range cases {
        input := T(tc.input)
        want := tc.want
        
        // Error: cannot use input (variable of type T constrained by Inputer) as type string in argument to fn
        got := fn(input)
        fmt.Printf("name: %-20s | input: %-10v | want: %-10v | got: %v\n", name, input, want, got)
    }
}

func main() {

    var cases = TestConditions[string, bool]{
        "empty":   {input: "", want: false},
        "integer": {input: "123", want: true},
        "float":   {input: "123.456", want: true},
    }
    fn := IsNumeric
    EvalCases(cases, fn)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why am I receiving that error

Because `fn` is a `BoolFunc`, which is a `func(string) bool`, thus requires a `string` as parameter, but `input` is of type `T`. Furthermore, by your definition, `T` satisfies the `Inputer` constraint, and thus can also assume type `int`, `float64` or any non-`string` type which has `string` as its underlying type (`~string`) none of which implicitly cast to `string`.

> how do I fix it?

You need to change the definition of `BoolCase` to itself have a generic type parameter for its one parameter. You could constraint it to `Inputer`, but you could also use `any` (`interface{}`).

```golang
type BoolCase[T any] func(T) bool
```

Then make sure to serve this generic type parameter in the signature of function `EvalCases`:

```golang
func EvalCases[T Inputer, U Wanter](cases TestConditions[T, U], fn BoolCase[T])
```

https://go.dev/play/p/RdjQXJ0WpDh

Comment: @Zyl, I assumed that an implementation of *type BoolCase[T any] func(T) bool* would result in me having to restructure the *IsNumeric* function?  Why don't I have to do so to satisfy the interface?

Comment: What would the restructured function look like? `string` satisfies `Inputer`; it's only the inverse which is not necessarily true. Generically typed values will assume concrete types at runtime, but at compile-time, your `T` and `U` won't be treated differently. Note that not all languages do it like that. C++ for instance demands to figure out all potential types to `T` at compile time to then figure out if the code could run. E.g. code using `+` operator on `T` values compiles fine generally as long as you don't pass a non-numeric type. Try playing with `reflect.TypeOf()`.